# Getting sum of similar pair and multiplying results to get a new column in same data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
df1 <- data.frame(first_pair1_1=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4),second_pair1_1=c(1,3,3,1,4,3,4),third_pair1_1=c(1,3,3,1,4,3,4),first_pair1_2=c(7,4,3,1,4,3,4),second_pair1_2=c(7,4,3,1,4,3,4),third_pair1_2=c(1,3,3,1,4,3,4),first_pair2_1=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4),second_pair2_1=c(1,3,3,1,4,3,4),third_pair2_1=c(1,3,3,1,4,3,4),first_pair2_2=c(7,4,3,1,4,3,4),second_pair2_2=c(7,4,3,1,4,3,4),third_pair2_2=c(1,3,3,1,4,3,4))
```

I have above data frame and I am trying to do following calculation:

```
(first_pair1_1 * second_pair1_1 * third_pair1_1) + 
(first_pair1_2 * second_pair1_2 * third_pair1_2) + 
(first_pair2_1 * second_pair2_1 * third_pair2_1) + 
(first_pair2_2 * second_pair2_2 * third_pair2_2)
```

I want to get result in a new column in same data frame. There could be more pairs but pattern will be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea via base R. We loop over the unique suffix of 1_1, 1_2, ..., and multiply all the columns that include each suffix (i.e. 1_1*1_1*1_1 and so on). We then use `rowSums` to add them, i.e.

```
ind <- unique(sub('.*pair', '', names(df1)))
rowSums(sapply(ind, function(i) Reduce(`*`, df1[grepl(i, names(df1))])))
#[1] 100 132 108   4 192 108 256
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce("+", lapply(split.default(df1, sub(pattern = "^[^_]*_", "", names(df1))),
                   function(a) Reduce("*", a)))
#[1] 100 132 108   4 192 108 256
```